# Knockout.js changing colour of <option> when using 'options' binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to alter the styling (using 'style' or 'css' binding) of a select list's option element when using the 'options' binding on a select list? Or can this only be done by using a 'foreach' on the select list and altering the styling for each ?

I have this in code:

```
<select id="components-select" size="4" name="components-select"
                        data-bind=" options: combinedComponents, 
                                    optionsText: 'displayName', 
                                    optionsValue: 'id', 
                                    value: chosenComponent"></select>
```

but if I append `style: {color:  isDefault() === true ? 'black' : 'red'}` then the entire list is coloured Red if `isDefault` returns false.

Is the only way to achieve this to code it this way:

```
<select id="components-select" size="4" name="components-select"
                        data-bind="foreach: combinedComponents">
    <option data-bind="value: id, text: displayName, style: {color: isDefault() === true ? 'black' : 'red'}"></option>
</select>
```

Or is there some form of Knockout.js wizardry that I am not aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: There aren't any wizardry options out there that I'm aware of. The default `options` binding handler only emits what is absolutely necessary the get the required semantics. And setting the color of each of the options was not a configurable setting. You could rewrite the handler to add those options. Possibly set the styles after the controls are rendered?

Comment: No there is no direct support for this in the KO `options` binding. But I think your second example with the manual `foreach` is the simplest solution for this problem.

Comment: If you're going to be doing anything like this more than just this one time, you're better off creating your own binding handler, using `options` as a guide, e.g. `optionsWithColor`

Comment: For anyone looking for this option, check out this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491607/knockout-conditional-styling-of-the-option-elements-of-an-unbound-select-eleme

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Thomas Wiersema's answer, the way you'd want to approach handling that on a per-row basis is something like:

```
<select id="components-select" size="4" name="components-select"
                    data-bind="foreach: combinedComponents">
<option data-bind="value: id, text: displayName, style: {color: getColorFor.call(null, $data) }"></option>
</select>
```

then, in JavaScript, attach a function to your parent object like so (I'm making some assumptions, of course, like your parent object being called `vm` and `isDefault` belonging to a combinedComponent):

```
vm.getColorFor = function(component) {
    return component.isDefault() === true ? 'black' : 'red';
}
```

If you're not sure what `call` does, check out [bind vs apply vs call](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/)

I hope that helps -- let me know if I can elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes that is the best way I believe.

with the code `style: {color: isDefault() === true ? 'black' : 'red'}` you bind(add) a style to the associated DOM element. In this case the whole `<select>` tag. Not a `<option>` tag like you want. That's why your *entire* list changes color.

Take a look at the [knockoutjs docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) for more info about style binding.

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'optionsAfterRender' Binding which in this case works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/cZRJN/243/

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  
  this.combinedComponents = ko.observableArray([{
displayName: 'item1',
id: 1,
isDefault:true
  }, {
displayName: 'item2',
id: 2,
isDefault:false
  }, {
displayName: 'item3',
id: 3,
isDefault:true
  }]);
  
  OptionsAfterRender = (option, item) => {
    
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {style: { color: item.isDefault ? 'red' : 'black'}}, item);
};
  
  
  this.chosenComponent= ko.observable(1);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id="components-select" size="4"  name="components-select"
                    data-bind=" options: combinedComponents, 
                                optionsText: 'displayName', 
                                optionsValue: 'id', 
                                value: chosenComponent,
                                  optionsAfterRender:OptionsAfterRender
                                "></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add up the what has already been said, there is one feature of Knockout that I find get's overlooked a lot and is very handy in these situations: `$index`. For example, I am making a list where I want the first option in the list to be black and the rest to be red. So I can just modify what you have as your second option like so:

`<select id="components-select" size="4" name="components-select"
                        data-bind="foreach: combinedComponents">
        <option data-bind="value: id, text: displayName, 
                           style: {color: $index === 0 ? 'black' : 'red'}"></option>
</select>`

Or if you want to alternate colors just use a modulus check.

`<select id="components-select" size="4" name="components-select"
                        data-bind="foreach: combinedComponents">
        <option data-bind="value: id, text: displayName, 
                           style: {color: $index % 2 === 1 ? 'black' : 'red'}"></option>
</select>`